# Unable to build .ipa with Nativescript 3.4.3

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript

I have upgraded a project from an older Nativescript version to 3.4.3

I've built it successfully on Windows for Android, both for release and debug configurations.

I'm unable to build a .ipa file for iOS for some reason.

*MacOS v 10.13.6*

*Xcode v 9.4.1 (9F2000)*

---

I'm new to {N} and complete and total noob to iOS and Apple development, so I might be missing something obvious.

---

Here is the error that I'm getting (after a long list of warnings)

[image: Xcode Error]

> 2018-08-03 14:48:53.399 xcodebuild[8392:54911] [MT] IDEDistribution:
>   -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path
>   '/var/folders/dx/5k9zt6wd2tn98nvc3wzlblj80000gp/T/bpa_2018-08-03_14-48-53.379.xcdistributionlogs'.
>   2018-08-03 14:48:55.949 xcodebuild[8392:54911] [MT] IDEDistribution:
>   Failed to generate distribution items with error: Error
>   Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=0 "Found an unexpected Mach-O header
>   code: 0x72613c21" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Found an unexpected
>   Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21,NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=}
>   2018-08-03 14:48:55.950 xcodebuild[8392:54911] [MT] IDEDistribution:
>   Step failed: :
>   Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=0 "Found an unexpected Mach-O
>   header code: 0x72613c21" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Found an
>   unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=} error: exportArchive: Found an
>   unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21
>
> Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=0 "Found an unexpected Mach-O
>   header code: 0x72613c21" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Found an
>   unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=}

I've googled around for `unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21` but I either did not understand the steps correctly or they did not resolve my issue. I've checked [this medium post](https://kobkrit.com/how-to-fix-found-an-unexpected-mach-o-header-code-0x72613c21-on-submitting-to-app-store-7d5b8ec180c) but it was not applicable (don't have a Frameworks directory in my copied bundle resources).

Here are my linked libraries and embedded frameworks if helpful:

[image: linked libraries and embedded frameworks]

My build.xconfig (my team id is correct):

[image: build.xconfig]

And my App_Resources/iOS/info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0.2</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires calendar access to function properly. To create social biking events</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```